# Azure B2C Sample Custom Policy, When SignIng In Shows 'Your password is incorrect'

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have followed the Getting Started workflow here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom

I followed it from scratch, twice, and have both times when trying to sign in with the sign-in & sign-up custom policy I am prompted with 'Your password is incorrect'. How can I properly authenticate?

Things that are working:

- When I do signup the user journey completes, and the user is added to the directory
- Using built in policies I can sign in and sign up
- Using built in policies I can sign in with a user who I used the custom policy to sign up for

Using Application Insights I can see the following errors. (some sanitation applied)

```
"ValidationRequest":{  
           "ContentType":"Unspecified",
           "Created":"2017-10-06T17:19:34.3995426Z",
           "Key":"ValidationRequest",
           "Persistent":true,
           "Value":"client_id=55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555&resource=cccccccc-cccc-cccc-cccc-cccccccccccc&username=MYUSERNAME&password=PASSWORDIENTEREDONSCREEN&grant_type=password&scope=openid&nca=1;1;login-NonInteractive;False"
        },

"ValidationResponse":{  
           "ContentType":"Json",
           "Created":"2017-10-06T17:19:34.3995426Z",
           "Key":"ValidationResponse",
           "Persistent":true,
           "Value":"{\"error\":\"invalid_client\",\"error_description\":\"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.\\r\\nTrace ID: 55555555-cccc-cccc-cccc-555555555555\\r\\nCorrelation ID: 77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777\\r\\nTimestamp: 2017-10-06 17:19:33Z\",\"error_codes\":[70002],\"timestamp\":\"2017-10-06 17:19:33Z\",\"trace_id\":\"55555555-cccc-cccc-cccc-555555555555\",\"correlation_id\":\"77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777\"};1;login-NonInteractive;False"
        },
```

The important bit seems to be:

> "AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion"

Also later it says:

> "Exception of type 'Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException' was thrown."

Some things I've double checked:

- In my Identity Experience Framework > Policy Keys, I have the following 4 keys after following the steps in the guide:

  - B2C_1A_AdminClientEncryptionKeyContainer
  - B2C_1A_FacebookSecret
  - B2C_1A_TokenEncryptionKeyContainer
  - B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer
- In the regular AAD > App registrations, I have the applications:

  - IdentityExperienceFramework
  - ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework
- And ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework has delegated Access IdentityExperienceFramework permissions from IdentityExperienceFramework.

  - And I've hit Grant permissions for both apps.
- Both application Ids were properly substituted in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml, two places each

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: it should work. Can you keenly check all the steps for both **Create the IdentityExperienceFramework application** and **Create the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application** you should create two apps at **Azure Active Directory** blade of B2C tenant

Comment: Is "55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555" the client identifier of the "ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework" application? Can you please paste your TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your *ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework* app was incorrectly created as a Web App/API. You need to recreate it as a Native app.** Make sure you don't forget to update the client_ids in your base policy to the new ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework accordingly.

The error *AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion* occurs when you try to obtain a token using a client_id for an application that was registered as a Web App/API but are not providing the required client_secret. In the case of Native app, there is no client_secret required.

When sign in, Azure AD B2C's trust framework (the thing that executes custom policies) internally attempts to obtain a token for the IdentityExperienceFramework app (Web API) using the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework app (Native app). If you incorrectly create the latter as a Web App/API, B2C's policy engine will fail to obtain the token which manifests itself as a *Your password is incorrect* error message to the user.

Comment: Oh, that did it. I figured it was some tiny detail I overlooked.
Thank you so much!