# Azure AD B2C custom policy for signin - Getting password incorrect message

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am trying to add simple SignIn custom policy in Azure AD B2C. When I run the policy, I can see the default sign-in page, but when I enter user email and password, I get below message.

> Your password is incorrect

I am entering the correct password, but still, I am facing the issue.

Below are my technical profile and user journey.

Technical Profile:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
      <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <!-- <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item> -->
        <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">False</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

User Journey:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn">
  <OrchestrationSteps>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
          <Value>objectId</Value>
          <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
      </Preconditions>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when in the token. -->
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>

    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

Do let me know what is missing.

Comment: The reset in the portal might not work. If it requires the user to change password on login, B2C won't be able to do that. You might need to update the password now using PowerShell / Graph API without the requirement to reset the password on login. Or delete the user and sign up again. Remember also that you cannot create a B2C user from the portal, they must sign up (or be created through Graph API).

Comment: Okay. But during signup, user adds their password. and while login, they use the same password but receive the mentioned error message

Comment: Based on your Base file, there seems to be nothing special. Did you create ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework app incorrectly as a Web App/API? It will allow you to sign up but when you sign in you will get the incorrect password error as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611968/azure-b2c-sample-custom-policy-when-signing-in-shows-your-password-is-incorrec.

Comment: @Allen, Yes the ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework app is native.